# svn server - can I force all commit operations to occur at the "top-level" directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The **top-level** checkout directory is `project` and you make a change in `project/dir1/dir2/main.cpp`

It appears that whether you execute a commit operation from inside `project/dir1/dir2/` vs `project/dir1/` vs `project/` actually does matter when it comes to branching/merging because of how svn **mergeinfo** is used for ancestry for our trunk rebase/merge operations.

We have many tree/ancestry conflicts because someone did a checkin, using TSVN, on `project/dir1/dir2/` folder instead of the top-level `project/` folder and some merge meta-info didn't get propagated up to `project/`.

**QUESTION**

On the server, is it possible to configure a commit rule that only allows checkins if they are performed on a designated top-level folder?

I *think* this only matters if there is a local change, like a merge into WC, that changes the WC. Therefore, I think it'd be hard to enforce because if user did commit the top-level, there simply might not be any changes to the **mergeinfo** but the server has no way of knowing this apriori so . . . I think this has to be implemented on the client side?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Are you looking for someone to write the pre-commit hook for you which looks at the changed paths and only permits it if they match your designated root?

Comment: @alroc is it possible to do this on server-side? It would be easier than syncing the client-side pre-commit hook scripts on all our PCs. At first glance, seems this is not possible. Does the server get told upon which path the `commit` command is executed?

Comment: You have to do it on the server side. The server does not have any knowledge of the filesystem path being operated on by the client, but it *does* know the path of every item contained in the transaction you're attempting to commit. And that is what you'll need to test here.

Comment: @alroc problem is that it's definitely possible you're only committing one item which is not on the root which is perfectly valid.
Problem is when you have merged-in from trunk to your branch and `mergeinfo` has been modified and someone performs a commit on NOT the top-level.